# Dynamic excel chart doesn't display all of the data

Tags: excel, excel-charts, vba

I have this code that allows users to enter chart parameters into some cells and dynamically create a chart. Many series (up to four) are allowed on two vertical (y) axis and one shared horizontal (x) axis. The chart is a mixture of columns and lines normally, and the data ranges are of varying length. I have this code that adds the series like so (I'll try to stick to what I believe is the relevant code)

```
 seriesCount = 1
 If hasSeries1 = True Then
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Name = .Cells(2, 6) & " " & axisside1
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).ChartType = chartType1
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).AxisGroup = axisgroup1
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Border.LineStyle = borderStyle1
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Border.Color = lineColor1
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Line.Weight = lineWidth1
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = seriesColor1
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Line.Visible = hasLine1
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).XValues = dates1
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Values = dataset1
   seriesCount = seriesCount + 1
 End If
 If hasSeries2 = True Then
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Name = .Cells(3, 6) & " " & axisside2
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).ChartType = chartType2
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).AxisGroup = axisgroup2
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Border.LineStyle = borderStyle2
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Border.Color = lineColor2
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Line.Weight = lineWidth2
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = seriesColor2
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Line.Visible = hasLine2
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).XValues = dates2
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Values = dataset2
   seriesCount = seriesCount + 1
 End If
 If hasSeries3 = True Then
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Name = .Cells(4, 6) & " " & axisside3
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).ChartType = chartType3
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).AxisGroup = axisgroup3
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Border.LineStyle = borderStyle3
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Border.Color = lineColor3
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Line.Weight = lineWidth3
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = seriesColor3
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Line.Visible = hasLine3
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).XValues = dates3
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Values = dataset3
   seriesCount = seriesCount + 1
 End If
 If hasSeries4 = True Then
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Name = .Cells(5, 6) & " " & axisside4
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).ChartType = chartType4
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).AxisGroup = axisgroup4
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Border.LineStyle = borderStyle4
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Border.Color = lineColor4
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Line.Weight = lineWidth4
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = seriesColor4
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Format.Line.Visible = hasLine4
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).XValues = dates4
   ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesCount).Values = dataset4
 End If
```

Here is the problem: the chart only displays part of the data it is supposed to. When I right-click on the data series, hit `Select Data` and choose `Edit`, the correct series (both x and y) become highlighted, but what is being shown is a truncated subset of what should be there.

Here is a sample of what I'm seeing

[image: myChart]

Here is some of the data for the light blue column

```
12/30/2005       307%
1/31/2006        302%
2/28/2006        248%
3/31/2006        262%
4/28/2006        285%
5/31/2006        256%
...              ...
...              ...
...              ...
6/30/2014        147%
```

Notice how this data should be showing on the chart beginning at 12/30/2005, but it's starting at 11/30/2013 instead (though the values appear to be correct, 307%, 302%, etc.). It is almost as though excel is forcing the 2nd and 3rd data series to be the same length as the first one. The first one is charting correctly.

Comment: What's the value of dataset1 to dataset4?

Comment: @L42 They are ranges that could be just about any length that matches the length of the corresponding `dates*` range.

Comment: In what way is the chart truncated? Post an image of the chart. What are the max values for the chart axes? Do they encompass the whole extent of the value ranges?

Comment: Ok. But are they returning the correct target ranges. When you select data and edit, does the actual data range you expect is all highlighted?

Comment: Just saw your edit. I think it has something to do with the axis assignment.

Comment: @L42 yes, what is highlighted is exactly what I expect to see. It's just what is on the chart is not what I expect to see. The x axis isn't lining up correctly and only some of the values are displayed.

Comment: @teylyn Yes, I set the max and min values to be the endpoints of the x value ranges programmatically.

Comment: `axisgroup*` just takes on values of either 1 or 2.

Comment: Share a reduced version of the file. Include one chart that shows the problem. Include the data source for just that chart.

Comment: @teylyn I added some data that corresponds to the chart image.

Comment: The problem is not with the data. It is with the Excel file. I'd need to see and inspect the chart in a workbook.

Comment: Yep. Just 1 and 2. That is for primary and secondary axis. Make sure that the series that's meant to go to primary axis goes to it and not on the secondary axis.

Comment: @L42 I verified that they are being assigned to the correct axis. :(

Comment: It is as though if any of the horizontal (x) axis ranges is shorter than the others, then all of them are squeezed into being that length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're not using a XY chart, thus you must have the same **labels** (Xvalues = dates for you) for every series. That means that you need to create a unique **dates**-set containing all the dates and assign it (as Xvalues) to the first serie.

Comment: You might be on to something here. I am investigating this and will get back to you.

Comment: It looks like you hit the nail on the head. Thank you. What troubles me is that this, then, appears to preclude me from working with columns or lines. It would seem like excel isn't the most flexible when it comes to charting.